# Error al ejecutar funcion

Tags: javascript

Porque el resultado *esperado*(5 * 4 = 20), no resulta en este, pero si en `undefined`?

```js
function anyMe(callback) {
    
    callback(5,4);
    
}
var expresion = anyMe(function(a,b){
    
    return a * b;
    
});



window.addEventListener("load",function(){
     
  
    document.write(expresion);
    
},false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Es simplemente porque la funcion `anyMe` aunque ejecuta tu callback, no retorna nada, puedes corregirlo así:

```js
function anyMe(callback) {    
    return callback(5,4);    
}
var expresion = anyMe(function(a,b){    
    return a * b;    
});

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    document.write(expresion);    
},false);
```